# Failure encrypting web.config using RSA and file path

Tags: asp.net, iis, encryption, rsa

I am using the following command in order to encrypt a file

```
aspnet_regiis -pef "connectionStrings" "d:\MyPath\web.config"
```

I get the following answer

```
The configuration for physical path 'd:\MyPath\web.config' 
cannot be opened.
Failed!
```

The file is not in a read only mode and I run cmd with admin privileges.

Any Idea?

Comment: Is the C: vs. D: difference intentional?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`aspnet_regiis -pef`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k6h9cz8h(v=vs.110).aspx) takes the *webApplicationDirectory* as a parameter, and should not include the file name of the web.config;

```
aspnet_regiis -pef "connectionStrings" "D:\MyPath"
```